# Adding <style> tag using tinyMCE

Tags: tinymce, tinymce-4, tinymce-plugins

I would like to add `<style>` tag using tinyMCE editor.

In my init code I added:

```
valid_elements: "*[*]",
valid_children: "+body[style]",
```

Now when I adding:

```
<style>
   .myTag{width:10px}
</style>
```

the result is:

```
 <style>
   <!-- .myTag{width:10px} -->
  </style>
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: What issue do you have with what the editor did?  That code validates for both HTML and XHTML if in the head of the document so it is "valid" other than the fact you want it within the body of the content.

Comment: I was not aware it's actually not commenting the style rule.  thanks.